# Should I go all in every time I got a full house?

Tags: strategy

In general, should it be profitable in the long run to go all in every time your hole cards end up with a full house by show down?

This is including all what ifs... I have a full house at some point during the hand, should I simply shove all in? Prolly not eh? What are the odds?

The game is full ring no limit hold em.

Comment: This is not really an answerable question, but here are a few considerations: (1) If you shove as soon as you make a full house, your opponents might just fold, whereas if you bet small or check they might continue or bet/raise (either for value or as a bluff). (2) Seeing more cards might let opponents "catch up" to a better hand (but still weaker than yours). (3) Unless you have the best possible full house, you will sometimes be beaten (especially if there are two pairs on the board). If you are playing very deep stacked and your opponent wants to play for all the money, be cautious.

Comment: Had KQ hole cards, flop showed KQQ. Went all in. Other player also went all in. Eventually other player showed KK.  This was the second round of holdem for the night, and I was first-out again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be profitable? Yes. Almost anything you do except for folding will be profitable when you have a full house.

Would it be maximally profitable? No. When you have a full house, you block a lot of your opponents' continuing range, so unless there is something to indicate your opponent has a hand strong enough to call, you will usually profit more with a smaller bet size. Also, your opponents don't have to be geniuses to eventually notice if every time you make a massive overbet, you have a monster. Which means that perceptive opponents will have an easy fold, unless you start balancing your all-ins with some bluffs. But it gets worse. Good opponents will also eventually discover that when you don't bet all-in, you can't have a full house, which they can use to exploit you when the board pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Their is several different ways to make a full house in texas holdem

1. one pair is on the board (the best kind of full house to make because its hard to detect/go all in all of the time)
2. 3 of a kind are on the board (second best/ go all in all of the time if your pair is higher than the other  card(s) on the board) If you have one of the 2 cards on the board  go all in with the higher one most of the time but  practice caution with the lower one
3. 2 pair are on the board and you have the fifth card (3rd best/ similar to 3 of a kind on the board go all in all the time with the higher set and practice caution with the lower one,)
4. 3 of a kind and a pair are on the board (worst kind/ playing the board / don't go all in) their is many situations where playing a full house on the board is a losing hand, so don't go all in unless you're pot committed.

If you have a full house that is made up of only one pair on the board and your opponent goes "All in" first then yes go All in with him. Those are the best kind of full houses because they rarely lose to a better full house. If the board has  3 of a kind or 2 pair on it you might lose to a better full house so practice caution with those kinds of full houses.